# Is there a tree-sitter grammar for .scm file

Tags: treesitter

I am working on a tree-sitter related application, hence it contains .scm files to describe my queries. I would like to run the application on the code of the application itself, but I am unable to find a tree-sitter grammar for the .scm files.

Does this grammar exists? Where could I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one.
It can be found at https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-tsq